# Global CSS cannot be imported from within node_modules

Tags: next.js

My project is using internal library which has `react-perfect-scrollbar` in one of it's components. Upon rendering my Next.Js application I get this error:

```
./node_modules/react-perfect-scrollbar/dist/css/styles.css
Global CSS cannot be imported from within node_modules.
Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/css-npm
Location: node_modules/some-organization/my-components/dist/index.js
```

I tried researching online but all of the cases deal with local `css` files, in my case, I cannot go back to `some-organization` and ask them to refactor their components and in turn ask `react-perfect-scrollbar` team to refactor theirs. How to solve this?

- I don't have `next.config.js` everything is default.
- React version 18.2.0
- Next.Js version 13.4.4